# selecting given entries of cell without loop

Tags: matlab

```
corrects = 

[1x4 double]    [1x4 double]    [1x4 double]    [1x4 double]    [1x4 double]    [1x4 double]    [1x4 double]    [1x4 double]    [1x4 double]    [1x4 double]


corrects{1}

ans =

 9     8    10     7
```

how to put it in a matrix every first entry of the 10 corrects cell without loop?

```
 So I need :

 corrects{1}(1)

 ans =

 9

 corrects{2}(1)

 ans =

 8
```

I tried corrects{:}(1)

but obviously bad cell reference how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`cellfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/cellfun.html) like this:

```
A = cellfun(@(x) x(1), corrects)
```

Here is an example to show you that it works:

```
>> corrects{:}
ans =
    0.9572    0.4854    0.8003    0.1419

ans =
    0.4218    0.9157    0.7922    0.9595

ans =
    0.6557    0.0357    0.8491    0.9340

ans =
    0.6787    0.7577    0.7431    0.3922

ans =
    0.6555    0.1712    0.7060    0.0318


>> A = cellfun(@(x) x(1), corrects)

A =
    0.9572    0.4218    0.6557    0.6787    0.6555
```